# Want To show And Hide Element using Boolean true false

Tags: javascript

I have Div Container,which i want to show and hide by clicking a button. But i want to do it using **Boolean True false valu

```js
function myFunction() {
let booleanValue = true;
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (booleanValue === true) {
    x.style.display = "block";
    booleanValue = false;
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

e**.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your code needs to be changed

```js
 
let booleanValue = true;
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (booleanValue) {
    x.style.display = "none";
    booleanValue = false;
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  booleanValue = true;
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very basic thing, I would recommend you to try little bit

```js
var isDivHidden = true;
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (isDivHidden === true) {
    x.style.display = "block";
    isDivHidden = false;
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    isDivHidden = true;
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick=myFunction()> Show/Hide </button>
<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I just want to get it by using Boolean only

Comment: I have updated the code with variable, but when you can achieve the same thing without, why would you need it with a variable? any specific reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a global variable. Rather than defining `let booleanValue = true;` inside `myFunction` define it outside the function as a global variable. So that each time the function executes, you can toggle the value of the variable.

```js
var booleanValue = true;
function myFunction() {
  booleanValue = !booleanValue;
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (booleanValue === true) {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Toggle Div</button>
<div id="myDIV">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```js
let booleanValue = true;

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (booleanValue) {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
  booleanValue = !booleanValue;
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">
Click here
</button>
<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

*The changes*:

- I've moved the `booleanValue` variable outside the function scope.
  I've modified the `myFunction()` to set the `booleanValue` to its opposite every time every time it gets executed.
- I've added a `button` which will execute `myFunction()`

Answer (score 0):

Because `booleanValue` always sets `true` whenever clicking the `myDiv`. The answer is easy. You just assign `booleanValue` out of `myFunction`.

The reason `booleanValue` always sets `true` is that the variable is set in the `myFunction` function. In Javascript codes in curly brackets `{}` of `function` only are executed in curly brackets like below,

```
function myFunction() {
executeA();
executeB();
}
executeC();
```

When you execute function `myFunction` then only `executeA()`, `executeB()` are executed not `executeC()`. It's because only codes in the curly brackets `{}` are executed.

In your code, likewise variable `booleanValue` has been assigned in `myFunction()`

```
function myFunction() {
let booleanValue = true;
  if (booleanValue === false) {
    ...
  }
}
```

But when you want to execute codes under condition `booleanValue === false`, the codes under the condition can not be executed as `booleanValue = true` whenever `myFunction` is executed.

If you want to know about executing codes within `{}`, read [lexical scope](https://www.google.com/search?q=lexical+scope+js&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk03qme5fxFlmuVizRxtVxOlQEvXe2A%3A1626937059373&ei=4xb5YPSnFsbnwQPngLa4BQ&oq=lexical+scope+&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYATICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAA6BQgAELADOgkIABCwAxAHEB5KBAhBGAFQvrYBWL62AWCrwgFoAXAAeACAAdYBiAHLApIBBTAuMS4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCsABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz).

```js
let booleanValue = true;
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (booleanValue === true) {
    x.style.display = "block";
    booleanValue = false;
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    booleanValue = true;
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>
```